# Should I write my comment as an answer if it appears to be true answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, ethics

I know comments are for getting details about question and so but some questions have little answer like "you forgot to put a ',' in here". When i wrote this and then it solves the problem should i write my comment as an answer to get reputation. I mean I  know Stackoverflow isn't just for getting reputation. I don't think i should do this, its just +15 eventually, and this site is not Facebook, people shouldn't be answering question for reputation. I just wanted to ask for future, since I'm new to this community.

Comment: Sure. This comment is too short to be answer though.

Comment: Frankly, if the answer **is** "you forgot to put a ',' in here", the question should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often questions with typo based answers should be closed and deleted. But, if we assume the question is not closeworthy then the answer should always be as an answer,  not as a comment.

This process will also encourage you to expand upon an answer, explaining exactly why the answer works; try to make your answer a better version of the comment. Not to mention the ability for people to vote on the correctness of the answer and its prominent display.